What type of hex bolt is this
The hand held shower cord broke and I’m trying to replace it however the faucet has a weird hex bolt and I'm struggling to determine what the replacement is and what it would be called?

it is custom made, only OEM will have it

This is not a bolt. The blue indicates it is from the cold side so this is a proprietary connection to your shower housing.

You have two parts together.
The part marked with purple gets unscrewed from the part marked in yellow.
The yellow part is screwed back into the shower control. The purple part is discarded and replaced with a new shower hose.

